# Multiple arithmetic operation in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have this awk function to do speed conversion.

```
function hum(x) {
  split( "B/s KB/s MB/s GB/s TB/s", v); s=1
  while( x>1000 ){ x/=1000; s++ }
  printf( "%0.2f %s" , x , v[s] )
}
hum($1)
```

It works great if used standalone.

```
$ awk -f /tmp/test.awk <<< 1000000
1000.00 KB/s
$ awk -f /tmp/test.awk <<< 100000000
100.00 MB/s
```

Now, I want to convert bytes number to bit, to do that I need to multiple the number/input first by 8. I tried to modify the function a bit.

```
function hum(x) {
  split( "B/s KB/s MB/s GB/s TB/s", v); s=1
  while( x>1000 ){ res = x * 8 / 1000; s++ }
  printf( "%0.2f %s\n" , res , v[s] )
}
hum($1)
```

But it hangs when I tried to execute it, I had to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to cancel the operation. Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Looks to me your `x` variable is not getting change(unlike your first code), hence its creating a infinite loop condition may be that's the reason its hanging and you have to put control C to come out of it. try fixing that part and it should be Good then IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, let's use `log()`:

```
$ cat program.awk
function hum2(x,   v,p) {
  split( "b/s kb/s Mb/s Gb/s Tb/s", v)             # remember to B -> b
  x*=8                                             # to bits conversion
  p=int(log(x)/log(1000))                          # figure v slot
  return sprintf("%0.2f %s" , x/1000^p , v[p+1] )  # p+1 due to 1 basedness
}
{
    print $1,hum2($1)                              # input bytes, output bits
}
```

Take it for a spin:

```
$ for (( i=1 ; i<=10**14 ; i=i*10 )) ; do echo $i ; done | awk -f program.awk
```

Output:

```
1 8.00 b/s
10 80.00 b/s
100 800.00 b/s
1000 8.00 kb/s
10000 80.00 kb/s
100000 800.00 kb/s
1000000 8.00 Mb/s
10000000 80.00 Mb/s
100000000 800.00 Mb/s
1000000000 8.00 Gb/s
10000000000 80.00 Gb/s
100000000000 800.00 Gb/s
1000000000000 8.00 Tb/s
10000000000000 80.00 Tb/s
100000000000000 800.00 Tb/s
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now, I want to convert bytes number to bit, to do that I need to multiple the number/input first by 8.

Then multiply the input value by 8 just once:

```
function hum(x) {
  split("b/s Kb/s Mb/s Gb/s Tb/s", v); s=1
  x *= 8
  while(x > 1000) {x /= 1000; s++}
  printf("%0.2f %s\n", x, v[s])
}
hum($1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this one a while back that might not be exactly what you need but should be easily adaptable -

- a `function` that takes in `# of bytes` as mandatory 1st parameter,
- with optional 2nd param for calculating powers of `1000` instead of `1024`

  - enter `M` `m` or `10`            `for         1000`,
  - anything else, including blank, `defaults to 1024`
- and auto formats it in the most logical range for human readability,

  - spanning all the way from `kilo(kibi)-bit/s`,
  - to ***`YOTTA`***`(yobi)-bit/s`

*** *extra credit for anyone who can figure out what's common among that list of numbers in my sample below.*

——————————————————————— ———————————————————————

```
mawk/gawk '
function bytesformat(_, _______, __, ___, ____, _____, ______)
{
    _____=__=(____^=___*=((____=___+=___^="")/___)+___+___)
     ___/=___
    
    sub("^0+","",_)
    ____=_____-=substr(_____,index(_____,index(_____,!__)))*\
                (_______ ~ "^(10|[Mm])$")
    _______=length((____)____)

    if ((____*__)<(_______*_)) {
        do {
            ____ *= _____
            ++___
        } while ((____*__)<(_______*_))
    }
    __=_
    sub("(...)+$",             ",&", __)
    gsub("[^#-.][^#-.][^#-.]", "&,", __)
    gsub("[,]*$|^[,]+",          "", __)
                   sub("^[.]", "0&", __)

    return \
    sprintf(" %10.4f %sb/s (%42s byte%s) ",
             _==""?+_:_/(_____^___)*_______,
             substr("KMGTPEZY",___,___~___),
                              __==""?+__:__, (_~_)<_?"s":" ")

 } { printf("%35s bytes ::: %s\n",
                          $1, 
              bytesformat($1, 10)) }'


                           6841 bytes :::     54.7280 Kb/s (                                     6,841 bytes) 
                          15053 bytes :::    120.4240 Kb/s (                                    15,053 bytes) 
                          23677 bytes :::    189.4160 Kb/s (                                    23,677 bytes) 
                          32839 bytes :::    262.7120 Kb/s (                                    32,839 bytes) 
                          42293 bytes :::    338.3440 Kb/s (                                    42,293 bytes) 
                          52183 bytes :::    417.4640 Kb/s (                                    52,183 bytes) 
                          62233 bytes :::    497.8640 Kb/s (                                    62,233 bytes) 
                          72733 bytes :::    581.8640 Kb/s (                                    72,733 bytes) 
                          83269 bytes :::    666.1520 Kb/s (                                    83,269 bytes) 
                         138641 bytes :::      1.1091 Mb/s (                                   138,641 bytes) 
                         149767 bytes :::      1.1981 Mb/s (                                   149,767 bytes) 
                         162011 bytes :::      1.2961 Mb/s (                                   162,011 bytes) 
                         174221 bytes :::      1.3938 Mb/s (                                   174,221 bytes) 
                         186343 bytes :::      1.4907 Mb/s (                                   186,343 bytes) 
                         199181 bytes :::      1.5934 Mb/s (                                   199,181 bytes) 
                         211559 bytes :::      1.6925 Mb/s (                                   211,559 bytes) 
                         224449 bytes :::      1.7956 Mb/s (                                   224,449 bytes) 
                         237733 bytes :::      1.9019 Mb/s (                                   237,733 bytes) 
                      128260807 bytes :::      1.0261 Gb/s (                               128,260,807 bytes) 
                      128565049 bytes :::      1.0285 Gb/s (                               128,565,049 bytes) 
                      128932561 bytes :::      1.0315 Gb/s (                               128,932,561 bytes) 
                      129304523 bytes :::      1.0344 Gb/s (                               129,304,523 bytes) 
                      129765859 bytes :::      1.0381 Gb/s (                               129,765,859 bytes) 
                      130111459 bytes :::      1.0409 Gb/s (                               130,111,459 bytes) 
                      130533133 bytes :::      1.0443 Gb/s (                               130,533,133 bytes) 
                      131012801 bytes :::      1.0481 Gb/s (                               131,012,801 bytes) 
                      131305043 bytes :::      1.0504 Gb/s (                               131,305,043 bytes) 
                   128004093619 bytes :::      1.0240 Tb/s (                           128,004,093,619 bytes) 
                   128026268633 bytes :::      1.0242 Tb/s (                           128,026,268,633 bytes) 
                   128056111093 bytes :::      1.0244 Tb/s (                           128,056,111,093 bytes) 
                   128071706179 bytes :::      1.0246 Tb/s (                           128,071,706,179 bytes) 
                   128082430067 bytes :::      1.0247 Tb/s (                           128,082,430,067 bytes) 
                   128102475287 bytes :::      1.0248 Tb/s (                           128,102,475,287 bytes) 
                   128115312811 bytes :::      1.0249 Tb/s (                           128,115,312,811 bytes) 
                   128157555781 bytes :::      1.0253 Tb/s (                           128,157,555,781 bytes) 
                   128175556181 bytes :::      1.0254 Tb/s (                           128,175,556,181 bytes) 
                128004004377827 bytes :::      1.0240 Pb/s (                       128,004,004,377,827 bytes) 
                128040044659991 bytes :::      1.0243 Pb/s (                       128,040,044,659,991 bytes) 
                128074066014953 bytes :::      1.0246 Pb/s (                       128,074,066,014,953 bytes) 
                128127783733093 bytes :::      1.0250 Pb/s (                       128,127,783,733,093 bytes) 
                128177777757611 bytes :::      1.0254 Pb/s (                       128,177,777,757,611 bytes) 
                128200131001829 bytes :::      1.0256 Pb/s (                       128,200,131,001,829 bytes) 
                128221782218423 bytes :::      1.0258 Pb/s (                       128,221,782,218,423 bytes) 
                128237784424429 bytes :::      1.0259 Pb/s (                       128,237,784,424,429 bytes) 
                128262808216561 bytes :::      1.0261 Pb/s (                       128,262,808,216,561 bytes) 
             128055360778053559 bytes :::      1.0244 Eb/s (                   128,055,360,778,053,559 bytes) 
             128082834342828077 bytes :::      1.0247 Eb/s (                   128,082,834,342,828,077 bytes) 
             128112814740831073 bytes :::      1.0249 Eb/s (                   128,112,814,740,831,073 bytes) 
             128172605482718161 bytes :::      1.0254 Eb/s (                   128,172,605,482,718,161 bytes) 
             128203333333333399 bytes :::      1.0256 Eb/s (                   128,203,333,333,333,399 bytes) 
             128240343634404269 bytes :::      1.0259 Eb/s (                   128,240,343,634,404,269 bytes) 
             128272818280928081 bytes :::      1.0262 Eb/s (                   128,272,818,280,928,081 bytes) 
             128282816070718271 bytes :::      1.0263 Eb/s (                   128,282,816,070,718,271 bytes) 
             128289494449498271 bytes :::      1.0263 Eb/s (                   128,289,494,449,498,271 bytes) 
          128030578058078030329 bytes :::      1.0242 Zb/s (               128,030,578,058,078,030,329 bytes) 
          128172161171772727271 bytes :::      1.0254 Zb/s (               128,172,161,171,772,727,271 bytes) 
          128234814212823481421 bytes :::      1.0259 Zb/s (               128,234,814,212,823,481,421 bytes) 
          128282727262616060507 bytes :::      1.0263 Zb/s (               128,282,727,262,616,060,507 bytes) 
          128286164949865319531 bytes :::      1.0263 Zb/s (               128,286,164,949,865,319,531 bytes) 
          128372737272827373721 bytes :::      1.0270 Zb/s (               128,372,737,272,827,373,721 bytes) 
          128393838393839382839 bytes :::      1.0272 Zb/s (               128,393,838,393,839,382,839 bytes) 
          128505500051850550037 bytes :::      1.0280 Zb/s (               128,505,500,051,850,550,037 bytes) 
          128669659758768758857 bytes :::      1.0294 Zb/s (               128,669,659,758,768,758,857 bytes) 
       130000000000093999992023 bytes :::      1.0400 Yb/s (           130,000,000,000,093,999,992,023 bytes) 
       131111111311113111311131 bytes :::      1.0489 Yb/s (           131,111,111,311,113,111,311,131 bytes) 
       131111153353153531553111 bytes :::      1.0489 Yb/s (           131,111,153,353,153,531,553,111 bytes) 
       131111531315333335313531 bytes :::      1.0489 Yb/s (           131,111,531,315,333,335,313,531 bytes) 
       131113133333311333331111 bytes :::      1.0489 Yb/s (           131,113,133,333,311,333,331,111 bytes) 
       131113551355135511111111 bytes :::      1.0489 Yb/s (           131,113,551,355,135,511,111,111 bytes) 
       131131113131113131131111 bytes :::      1.0490 Yb/s (           131,131,113,131,113,131,131,111 bytes) 
       131131331133111331313111 bytes :::      1.0491 Yb/s (           131,131,331,133,111,331,313,111 bytes) 
       131133133131333313331311 bytes :::      1.0491 Yb/s (           131,133,133,131,333,313,331,311 bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what's wrong ?

You have created infinte loop which cause it to hang, 1st code has

```
while( x>1000 ){ x/=1000; s++ }
```

here each turn decrease `x` 1000 times so it will finally be equal or lower 1000. 2nd code has

```
while( x>1000 ){ res = x * 8 / 1000; s++ }
```

here each turn `x` is used to compute `res` but value of `x` itself never changes, thus you will get either 0 executions of `while` body or +infinity executions of `while` body.

Note that *But it hangs when I tried to execute it* might be observed also in languages other than GNU `AWK` which do support `while` construct when you do not change value of variable on which truthiness of condition depends.